# quotation marks needed for variable name in timeit moduel, python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, timeit, variable-names

```
import random
import timeit
data = [random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(10)]
timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x : x>=0 ,"data")')
```

As shown in the code.
if I try to remove the "" from "data", it would throw an error.
Why? 
There is still a single quote containing the whole filter line.
Thank you for helping!!

Comment: Please don't post text as an image. There is a formatting button for making text look nice in the editor toolbar. Please use it.

Comment: This is my first post ever, sorry for the inconvenience. I tried to add the picture to text area and stackoverflow said I am not allowed to do that until I get some level up? Thank you though

Comment: Don't use an image; add the code itself (format it with 4 spaces on each line before the code) to the text area.

Comment: thank you! I will do that next time!

Comment: Not next time. Use the edit button under the question and do it this time please.

Comment: You do understand that your question will probably be closed if you don't fix it?

Comment: I tried but didn't find formatting button..

Comment: I changed image into codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x : x >= 0, {})'.format(data))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but why would data without quotation marks make the syntax wrong?

Comment: Not familiar with timeit, but it looks like it accepts strings as arguments. In this scenario without the double quotes, it is recognizing your argument as one entire string, instead of a string with a variable.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

data is string and it should be under quote "" unless you store it in another variable like

```
data="data"
```